# Spring boot JPA Postgres enrity not being save

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Spring Boot JPA Postgres.

The entity is not being saved  while no apparent exception is there the logs .

#### The Entity : TransactionInfo.java

```
package com.demo.kmd.models;

import java.util.List;

import com.plaid.client.response.TransactionsGetResponse.Transaction.Location;
import com.plaid.client.response.TransactionsGetResponse.Transaction.PaymentMeta;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "spendschema.transaction")
public  class TransactionInfo {  
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long genId;                                 //generated id locally in database .

private String accountId;
private Double amount;
private String isoCurrencyCode;
private String unofficialCurrencyCode;


private String categoryId;
private String date;

private String name;
private String originalDescription;

private Boolean pending;
private String pendingTransactionId;
private String transactionId;
private String transactionType;
private String accountOwner;

public String getTransactionId() {
  return transactionId;
}

public String getAccountId() {
  return accountId;
}

public Boolean getPending() {
  return pending;
}

public String getPendingTransactionId() {
  return pendingTransactionId;
}

public String getTransactionType() {
  return transactionType;
}


public String getDate() {
  return date;
}

public String getName() {
  return name;
}

public Double getAmount() {
  return amount;
}


}
```

#### TransactionJpaReposotory.java

```
package com.demo.kmd.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.demo.kmd.models.TransactionInfo;

@Component
public interface TransactionJpaRepository extends  CrudRepository<TransactionInfo, Long>{   

}
```

#### PersistanceService.java

```
package com.demo.kmd.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.demo.kmd.models.TransactionInfo;
import com.demo.kmd.repository.TransactionJpaRepository;

@Service 
public class PersistanceService {


@Autowired
TransactionJpaRepository transactionJpaRepository;  

public TransactionInfo insert(TransactionInfo transactionInfo) {

    return transactionJpaRepository.save(transactionInfo);

} 

}
```

#### TestController.java

```
package com.demo.controller;


import com.demo.kmd.models.TransactionInfo;
....
import retrofit2.Response;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.demo.kmd.service.PersistanceService;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;

@Controller
public class TestController {

@Autowired
PersistanceService persistanceService;

@RequestMapping(value="/test1", method=GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getTransactions3() throws Exception {

    System.out.print("test  hit");
    TransactionInfo transactionInfo =  new TransactionInfo();     

    transactionInfo.setAccountId("ACCOUNTID1234");
    transactionInfo.setAmount(4000.12);

    transactionInfo = persistanceService.insert(transactionInfo);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionInfo);            

}
```

#### Application.properties

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG

logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.23:5432/spenddb
spring.datasource.username= spenduser
spring.datasource.password= ***


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`
```

#### pgAdmin (postgres)

```
select * from spendschema.transaction
**No result `**
```

#### Logs:

```
019-12-07 10:02:49.406 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
test  hit2019-12-07 10:02:49.408 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@7fa03c3f] for JPA transaction
2019-12-07 10:02:49.408 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2019-12-07 10:02:49.408 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2019-12-07 10:02:49.416 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7b9fb713]
2019-12-07 10:02:49.418 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2019-12-07 10:02:49.423 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator       : Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Long[16]]
2019-12-07 10:02:49.424 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
2019-12-07 10:02:49.424 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Generated identifier: 16, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator
2019-12-07 10:02:49.425 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
2019-12-07 10:02:49.425 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@7fa03c3f]
2019-12-07 10:02:49.425 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2019-12-07 10:02:49.425 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
2019-12-07 10:02:49.425 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
2019-12-07 10:02:49.426 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
2019-12-07 10:02:49.426 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
2019-12-07 10:02:49.426 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
2019-12-07 10:02:49.426 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.demo.kmd.models.TransactionInfo{date=null, amount=4000.12, pending=null, accountOwner=null, transactionId=null, genId=16, transactionType=null, accountId=ACCOUNTID1234, name=null, unofficialCurrencyCode=null, pendingTransactionId=null, isoCurrencyCode=null, categoryId=null, originalDescription=null}
2019-12-07 10:02:49.427 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into spendschema_transaction (account_id, account_owner, amount, category_id, date, iso_currency_code, name, original_description, pending, pending_transaction_id, transaction_id, transaction_type, unofficial_currency_code, gen_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into spendschema_transaction (account_id, account_owner, amount, category_id, date, iso_currency_code, name, original_description, pending, pending_transaction_id, transaction_id, transaction_type, unofficial_currency_code, gen_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-12-07 10:02:49.437 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-12-07 10:02:49.440 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [com.demo.kmd.models.TransactionInfo@3e9d3604] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@129ecd4a]
2019-12-07 10:02:49.441 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2019-12-07 10:02:49.441 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-12-07 10:02:49.441 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2019-12-07 10:02:49.441 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl  : HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
2019-12-07 10:02:49.442 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2019-12-07 10:02:49.442 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@9687fb6
2019-12-07 10:02:49.443 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@7167dc63:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1ba33e7e:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53851]], Read from buffer: [0]
2019-12-07 10:02:49.443 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@7167dc63:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@1ba33e7e:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53851]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
2019-12-07 10:03:14.811 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1f62c78:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@30a5cb21:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53852]], Read from buffer: [0]
2019-12-07 10:03:14.812 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:717) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_181]

2019-12-07 10:03:14.813 DEBUG 3628 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@1f62c78:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@30a5cb21:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53852]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating `TransactionInfo transactionInfo =  new TransactionInfo();` using new keyword while it should be @Autowired since it's Spring driven service bean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your application.properties.

1. Change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update '` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`
2. Validate table created in log when spring boot starts.
3. Validate table is created in the database.
4. The error is related to reading data from the controller's infrastructure, it did not reach the `orm.xml` or its equivalent.
5. Suggest to start testing with a query request first.
6. Better to start testing with `POST` message for insert request.  And use `GET` message for query request.

Answer (score 0):

try by replacing **save**() to **saveAndFlush**(). It flushes the data immediately during the execution